# How to achieve same height for card(material ui)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have cards to render in the grid list of material-ui. Each card has an image file at the top and some content in the remaining part, whenever there is a difference in content(text) card height changes. As far now I have tried most of the things to achieve the same height for each card, none of them worked. I am providing codesandbox link below.

[working example of cards in grid list](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-satoshi-l4f0w?file=/src/App.js:1685-1815)

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to show your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Since your content area card (with the className "content") is to have fixed height for each card, you need to make sure the content-text is the same, or else you can give height to the content card like this :

```
 content: {
    height : "200px"
  },
```

[image: code]

This would produce this as output :

[image: Output image]

However, here the height of the content card is hardcoded, so you need to make sure the content size accordingly matches.

Comment: I have tried this way as well, it gives me the fix card height but with the amount of content buttons placement is changed. I want them to fixed at bottom of card. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You need to add display flex in your content style like this -> [Picture](https://imgur.com/a/JNMDfjt) . Also you need to make sure you are displaying the same length of text content , so for long text better show a fixed string of a length and add a read more kind of button (this will have the complete content string), so that the cards look even .

Answer (score -1):

In `CardContent` styling you should specify maxHeight and give it overflow. Something like:

```
<CardContent
                style={{
                  paddingBottom: "0%",
                  maxHeight: "100px",
                  overflow: "auto"
                }}>
```